# Сложная синтаксическая конструкция с собеседования

Tags: c++, стандарт, задание-на-собеседовании

```
auto fry()try{}catch(int){try{}catch(...){}}catch(int){}
```

Объясните, что означает эта конструкция. Почему некоторые компиляторы компилируют без ошибок (gcc), а некоторые - с (msvc)?. Как правильно с точки зрения стандарта?

Comment: За что минусы?!

Comment: Это просто не скомпилируется из-за повторного перехвата исключения одного и того же типа `int`... А так — попытка определения достаточно странной, **ничего не делающей**  функции.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @Harry компилируется https://godbolt.org/z/n44Gr75h5

Comment: А не должно бы... VC++ не  берет. Гуру в стандартах — как должен отрабатываться повторный перехват исключения одного и того же типа?

Comment: @user7860670 это не домашка, очевидно

Comment: @karmik - прекратите откатывать мою правку! Очевидно, что для того, чтобы понять, что написано в этой бубылде, ее надо сначала привести в порядок.

Comment: @Harry понятно, что ничего не делает. Смысл вопроса в объяснении, почему так

Comment: @gbg это часть ответа уже, а не вопроса. Вопрос в оригинальном виде представлен

Comment: Домашка или нет, но попытка самостоятельно что-то сделать все равно нужна. А вам было лень зайти на cppreference и прочитать пол странички. Даже отформатировать нормально не потрудились.

Comment: @karmik - у нас так не принято. У нас принято задавать вопросы в читаемом виде, как бы этого не хотели чуваки с собеседования.

Comment: @user7860670 90% вопросов так можно закрывать, т.к. в документации всё написано. Не знаю, при чём тут лень, если я сам вопрос задал этот

Comment: @gbg где в правилах сказано про форматирование кода (причём именно вашим стилем)?

Comment: Да, это так. Большая часть вопросов - дубликаты либо просто чья-то лень. *"если я сам вопрос задал этот"* - ну вопрос может быть и задал, а вот каких-то собственных соображений по его решению - нет. Или вы вообще только на собеседовании первый раз увидели конструкцию `try` `catch`?

Comment: @user7860670 но не этот, получается. Это явно не дубликат. А так как сам задал вопрос, то не лень, а наоборот - расширение базы знаний

Comment: @user7860670 это я задал этот вопрос на собеседовании, хватит уже

Comment: @karmik это вопрос банального уважения к тем, кто будет пытаться разобраться в вашем вопросе. Хорошо отформатированные вопросы и ответы более интересны и получают больше положительных оценок.

Вы можете оставить авторскую редакцию, а ниже дописать отформатированный (хоть Кармаком, хоть Египтом) вариант, чтобы читающие, которым лень разгребать белиберду из скобок проявили больше интереса к проблеме.

Comment: @karmik, о, вот мы и встретились, дорогой токсичный интервьюэр. Добро пожаловать! Надеюсь никогда с вами не работать в любом качестве.

Comment: "После этих слов и подтвердилась драка." М.Зощенко

Comment: @gbg я вас не заставляю разбирать, если вам лень. Разбор именно однострочного варианта - часть задания. Если бы это был обычный код, то форматировал бы, а так в этом часть смысла вопроса

Comment: @gbg меня называют токсичным после того, как один человек говорит, что мне лень посмотреть, что такое try catch, а второй пытается навязчиво отформатировать мой вопрос, часть смысла которого зависит от форматирования...welcome to ru.stackoverflow :D

Comment: Что тут непонятно? В `try`, где должно что-то делаться, ничего не делается. Раз ничего не делается — не генерируется и исключение, а значит, обработчики тоже не работают. Все, это просто пустая, ничего не делающая функция...

Comment: @Harry до этого вы говорили, что "Это просто не скомпилируется", а сейчас уже "Что тут непонятно? [] Все, это просто пустая, ничего не делающая функция". Значит, не всё так уж понятно и вопрос нетривиальный

Comment: Еще раз, медленно, как для милиционера. Если компилятор разрешает две конструкции `catch` для одного и того же типа исключения, т.е. если он скомпилирует **это**, то это — просто ничего не делающая функция. А вообще, пора вам ставить минус за то, что вы вопрос задали, а ответы слушать не хотите... :)

Comment: Да, вы всерьез считаете, что отформатированный код работает как-то иначе, чем код в одну строку? :)

Comment: "karmik — новый участник сайта. Будьте снисходительны. Почитайте про нормы поведения. " -> 1) вы вообще только на собеседовании первый раз увидели конструкцию try catch 2) вот мы и встретились, дорогой токсичный интервьюэр 3) Еще раз, медленно, как для милиционера.

Что может быть лучше старого доброго русского комьюнити?)

Comment: в чужой монастырь со своим уставом, лмао

Comment: @Harry а с какой ошибкой вижак на это плевался, не подскажите?

Comment: Знаете, я вам несколько раз пояснял, что к чему. Но вам, похоже, не нужен ответ? вы просто цепляетесь к словам...

Comment: @gbg *error C2312: int: перехвачено "int" в строке 5*

Comment: @Harry я услышал ваши комментарии (не ответы) по поводу "не скомпилируется или ничего не сделает", но меня, как уже говорилось, интересует, **почему** так произойдёт, желательно с подтверждением слов документацией

Answer (score 1):

Ну давайте сделаем разбор данной *бубылды*.

Первым делом, мы приведем *это* в читаемый вид (как престарелый квакер, я воспользуюсь [скобками Кармака](https://github.com/id-Software/Quake-2/blob/master/client/cl_inv.c)):

```
auto fry()
try
{
}
catch(int)
{
    try
    {
    }
    catch(...)
    {
    }
}
catch(int)
{
}
```

Нулевая причина посчитать это некорректным - у функции нету тела (Что? Да!) - смотрите, `try` идет вне блока кода, сразу за круглой скобкой, которой заканчивается список параметров. Но это всего лишь [function-try-block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block), [EN.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612486/when-is-a-function-try-block-useful) ничего страшного, так тоже писать можно.

Тут мы объявили функцию, которая, казалось бы, может возвращать что угодно (потому что тип стоит `auto`, что в данном случае сомнительно - шаблонов нет, паравозов из неймспейсов нет - почему бы не сократить пространство для ошибок. Более того, `C++11` и ниже это не примет, потому что auto для возврата из функций [завезли только в `C++14`](https://oopscenities.net/2018/03/04/auto-return-type-deduction/)). Фактичкески функция **ничего не делает** (как верно заметил в комментариях @Harry), поэтому на деле, она будет возвращать `void`.

Дальше у нас идет развесистая гирлянда из обработчиков исключений, которые никогда не полетят - просто потому что код в блоке `try` отсутствует.

Обработчики исключений обрабатываются сверху-вниз **и** в соответствии с возможностью преобразования типов ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch), TODO: выкопать параграфы в Стандарте). Вот тут очень важен союз **И**, потому что наличие двух обработчиков с одинаковой сигнатурой (или с возможностью приведения типов) стандарт допускает, но тот который ниже - никогда не вызовется:

```
try 
{
    f();
} 
catch (const std::exception& e) 
{
    // will be executed if f() throws std::runtime_error
} 
catch (const std::runtime_error& e) 
{
    // dead code!
}
```

Собственно, по этой причине, `GCC` этот код сожрал.

`MSVC` же считает, что это повод выругаться [ошибкой `C2312`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2312?view=msvc-160), причем пример, который они там приводят, по структуре и форме совпадает примером выше:

```
// C2312.cpp
// compile with: /EHsc
#include <eh.h>
int main() 
{
    try 
    {
        throw "ooops!";
    }
    catch( signed int ) {}
    catch( int ) {}   // C2312
}
```

С ними трудно спорить - раз такая оказия произошла, вероятно, это ошибка, человеческий фактор (перепутаны местами блоки или типы), вот и ругаемся.

`clang` же ограничивается выдачей Warning, но с тем же смыслом - негоже делать два обработчика с одинаковым (или приводимым) типом - работать будет только верхний.

В блоке обработки исключения есть еще вложенный блок, но так как там нет кода, ничего примечательного про него *в данный момент* сказать нельзя.

Comment: я пытался найти в стандарте про `void fun() try{}catch(...){}` без фигурных скобок тела функции, нашёл только фразы с конструктором `C::C()try{:i{},j{}}catch(...){}` и деструктором. Тоже непонятно, почему `g++` принимает такое : `int main()try{}catch(...){}` без фигурных скобок. Что стандарт про такое скажет?

Comment: @AlexGlebe - дописал абзац на эту тему.

Comment: на [Function-try-block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block) говорится, что в деструкторах и обычных функциях эта запись `void fun()try{}catch(...){}` редко используется, что и понятно, что незачем.